# How to do update in pyspark using and operator?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am trying to to update one of my columns in my dataframe by using and operators.
First Query

```
df1=df1.withcolumn('department',F.when(F.col('dateofjoining')<'2019-09-01','senior'). otherwise (''))
```

Second query which I am running after first query

```
    Newcolumn=when((col('department')=='') & (col('dateofjoining')<'2019-12-15'),'junior'). otherwise ('')
  df1=df1.withcolumn('department', Newcolumn)
```

When i am running the queries i am getting output of second query only but I need output from both the queries and all other fields should be null if it is not matching conditions. Please let me know if need more details.

Comment: both dataframe columns have the same name, meaning the second one overwrites the first one. are you hinting at this? or, are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, @samkart  i am not getting any errors if i am running my code till first query it is updating values in my department column as senior and for rest rows it is null but when i am running my second query it is giving junior data only. I want to run both these queries and fetch data from both

Comment: Date format is yyyy-mm-dd default spark date format

Comment: it's because of your `otherwise('')`. it sets (or resets) the values to `""`. you could chain multiple whens -- `func.when().when().otherwise()` will work fine. or, you can provide the same column name within `otherwise()`

Comment: Can you please show a code how we can implement this by using my code

Answer (score 0):

Here are my 2 cents

1. Create a dataframe:

   ```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F


    schema = StructType([ \
        StructField("department",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("dateofjoining",DateType(),True), \
    ])

    import datetime

    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            ('deptA',datetime.date(2019, 8, 1)),
            ('deptB',datetime.date(2019, 12, 14)),
            ('deptC',datetime.date(2022, 12, 22)),
        ],
        schema=schema)

    df.show(truncate=False)
   ```
2. Construct a when-otherwise block as follows:

   ```
    df1=df.withColumn('department',
    F.when(F.col('dateofjoining')<'2019-09-01','senior')\
    .when(F.col('dateofjoining')<'2019-12-15','junior')\
    .otherwise (''))

    df1.show()
   ```

Please check the below image for reference:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Banu this is wrong i am using the same code you used but i am getting null values only in my column department. I can see that you have used only one condition in second query but there are two can you please check the question again

Comment: @dbd, Are you sure that the dateofjoining column is of type date but not string. can you update the question with the schema as well. As you see I have added 2 conditions using when otherwise ladder in a SINGLE query

Answer (score 0):

In the above the **second query is overwriting the first query results**. That is the reason for not getting correct results.

If you want to do it using `&` operator you can try the following.

First, I have added the department column with empty strings.

```
df=df.withColumn('department',F.lit(''))
```

[image]

Then used your query and in the otherwise use your column.

```
df=df.withColumn('department',F.when(F.col('date')<'2019-09-01','senior').otherwise(df['department']))
```

In the second query also use your column in the otherwise.

```
df=df.withColumn('department',F.when((F.col('department')=='') & (F.col('date')<'2019-12-15'),'junior').otherwise(df1['department']))
```

**Result:**

[image]

Also, in this case you can use `!='senior'` in the second query instead of `==''` after first query.

```
df=df.withColumn('department',F.when((F.col('department')!='senior') & (F.col('date')<'2019-12-15'),'junior').otherwise(df1['department']))
```

[image]